# Copy & fetch files in Ansible/Cygwin

Tags: ansible, cygwin

**Question - - how do you navigate the cygwin path structure for file transfers, copies and fetches?**

I've installed ansible on a windows 10 machine using cygwin.  Everthing works except for the `ansible.builtin.copy` task.  Here is the setup

```
Relevant Directory Structure
C:.
├───.github
│   └───workflows
├───files
    └───payload
        ├───communication
        ├───monitoring
```

The playbook sits in the documents directory of the user, so `.` is `C:/Users/user/Documents/`

```
Ansible Task
  - name: Download YAML payloads
    ansible.builtin.copy:
      src: payload
      dest: /some/directory/
```

The ansible cygwin command line actually runs from `/cygdrive/c/Users...` path.  I can navigate to the `payload` directory from either windows cli or the cygwin cli using their native paths.  [Must be a symlink?]  In any event - when I run the above task, the `src` directory is not found.

What I've tried - both absolute and relative path variables in the `src` line, for both the cywgin and the windows paths.  I've also tried using the inventory environment variables (`{{ playbook_dir }}`).  `fileglob:` didn't work either.

What I haven't tried - `{{ role_path }}`.  I'd like to keep the source YAMLs all together in the top directory.  But not sure if this would work by putting the `files` directory under a `role`.

**added details**

Path to playbook from windows
`C:\Users\billr\Documents\GitHub\home-k3s`

Path to playbook from cygwin
`/cygdrive/c/Users/billr/Documents/GitHub/home-k3`

files & directories

```
home-k3s
  files                    // these are the files/dirs I'm looking to copy
    payload
      communication
        first.yaml
        second.yaml
      monitoring
        first.yaml
        second.yaml
  hosts.ini                //contains playbook hosts.
  test.yml                //this is the playbook I'm running
```

playbook cat

```
---
- hosts: master
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Download YAML payloads
    ansible.builtin.copy:
      src: payload
      dest: /home/bill/
```

Run #1
`src: payload`  <-- this is the method per docs (for linux).

`result:  FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Source payload not found"}`

Run #2
`src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/files/payload"`

`result:  FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Source /cygdrive/c/Users/billr/Documents/GitHub/home-k3s/files/payload not found"}`

Run #3
`src: "/cygdrive/c/Users/billr/Documents/GitHub/home-k3s/files/payload"`

`result:  FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Source /cygdrive/c/Users/billr/Documents/GitHub/home-k3s/files/payload not found"}`

Run #4
`src: "c:/Users/billr/Documents/GitHub/home-k3s/files/payload"`

`FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Source c:/Users/billr/Documents/GitHub/home-k3s/files/payload not found"}`

Note that I can see the files from the cygwin terminal with `ls` and I can see the files from the windows cli with `dir`.

***Final Notes***

[Cygwin Github Issue Link](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/73575)

Comment: Can you show the emplacement of your playbook/roles in the directory tree you describe? (Playbook is in user documents but 'files/payload' folder is directly in 'c'?) Can you show the code of all the things you tried (relative path, absolute path)?

Comment: @zigarn - The entire project is in the directory `home-k3s`.  There are quite a few playbooks installing packages, upgrading, launching k8s and launching monitoring that all pull from somewhere other than `home-k3s`.  I've reduced to the minimum to isolate my issue.  I'm sure it has to do with the cygwin file system but can't figure out how to work around it.  This all works on an ubuntu vm - - so it's just this `copy` function from host to remote in a windows/cygwin environment.  :-(  Thanks.

Comment: How did you installed python and ansible in Cygwin? All in Cygwin? Or python on Windows and ansible in Cygwin with `pip`?

Comment: Windows - I don't think I installed as part of cygwin.  Ansible was in cygwin.

Comment: @zigarn - great follow-on question - - I've done some digging and realize have no idea how cygwin/ansible work together.

Comment: Ansible is officially not supported on Windows nor Cygwin (on controller side): https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_faq.html#can-ansible-run-on-windows
In older doc it was reported to "work" on Windows but with issues an no warranties.
I used to use it in Cygwin by installing python in Cygwin and ansible with pip.
Just discovered Cygwin now propose an 'ansible' package, no idea how it work.
What's the output of `ansible --version`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228588/discussion-between-bill-armstrong-and-zigarn).

Comment: That question, along with the created issue are very well documented - nicely done! Too bad they just used the #wontfix path, since ansible isn't supported on Windoze and Cygwin (I'm in this same boat, btw). Thank you!